# ocelot redirect to internal container failed

Tags: docker, ocelot

so I have a console app that needs to call the backend running on docker.
i'm using ocelot for api gateway and an api.

when I do a test call in postman to my gateway, the request come in and ocelot tries to redirect to the api, but I get a ENOTFOUND.

I'm using the docker-compose name, and I also tried with the container-name.

ocelot config:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/fileagent",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "fileagentapi",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/fileagent",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST"]      
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "RequestIdKey": "ocRequestId"
    
  }
}
```

port 80 is the internal docker container port.

docker-compose config:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  fileagentapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}fileagentapi
    container_name: FileAgentApi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/FileAgentApi/Dockerfile

  gateways:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}gateways
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Api-Gateways/Gateways/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 50000:443
      - 50001:80
```

Comment: Can you reach the api from inside the gateway container? Try `docker exec -it  gateways_containername sh ` and use `curl -v fileagentapi:80` inside the container.
Also please add `expose:
      - "80"` to the **fileagentapi service**

Comment: i'm getting a curl not found inside the container, but port 80 and 443 are exposed in the dockerfile

Comment: in my gateways container I got 307 redirect to: http://fileagentapi/api/fileagent

Comment: Are you sure you exposed port 80 for  **fileagentapi service** in the `docker-compose.yml `? 
You might need to install curl first inside the container to use it

Comment: @Calipee wait why expose port 80 in docker yaml file? if both the gateway and api are running in a container, they use internal docker network and ports no? -> but no exposing in docker yaml doesn't help

Comment: @Calipee when trying to install curl with the docker file and the do the curl command inside my api gateway container, yes I can connect to my api. I know my api gateway should work as it worked when running everything as kestrel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time but I have found my problem.

In my program file -> I still had the app.UseHttpsRedirect() enabled.
This will not work when testing in http.